# Problems running assync python file inside electron framework

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, async-await, electron

guys,

Please, I need some help.

My Electron desktop app runs a python script and I'm having a problem because when it runs, the app stays in 'not responding' and this is a huge problem for the users, because with one click while it's not responding the process will stop and the app will close.

How can I do it works properly?

in renderer.py:

```
saveAndExecuteButton.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
      const inputData = textInput.value;
      output.textContent = 'Executing';
      console.log('Save and execute button pressed.');
      
      electronAPI.sendToMain('saveAndExecute', inputData);

      alert('Data saved.');
    });
```

in main.js:

inside createWindow:

// Handle the event to save to SQLite and execute the Python script

```
ipcMain.on('saveAndExecute', (event, data) => {
    console.log('Received data to save to SQLite and execute the Python script:', data);
    saveToSQLiteAndExecuteScript(data);
  });
```

functions of the main process:

```
function saveToSQLiteAndExecuteScript(data) {
  console.log('Initiating the operation to save to SQLite...');
  // Connect to the SQLite database
  const db = new Database(path.join(__dirname, 'anansi.db'));

  // Create a table if it doesn't exist
  db.run('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS anansi (rowid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, link TEXT)');

  // Insert or update data in the table
  const stmt = db.prepare('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO anansi (rowid, link) VALUES (1, ?)');
  stmt.run(data, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error inserting/updating data in SQLite:', err.message);
    } else {
      console.log('Data inserted/updated into SQLite successfully!');
    }

    // Finalize the statement before closing the connection
    stmt.finalize();

    // Close the database connection
    db.close();
  });
  executePythonScript();
}
async function executePythonScript() {
  console.log('Executing the Python script...');

  const pythonExecutable = 'C:\\Users\\Gustavo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python.exe';
  const pythonScriptPath = path.join(__dirname, 'anansi.py');

  try {
    console.log('começou');
    const processResult = spawnSync(pythonExecutable, [pythonScriptPath], { encoding: 'utf8' });
    console.log('aqui é o then');
    
    if (processResult.error) {
      console.error('Error from the Python script:', processResult.error);
    } else {
      console.log('Output from the Python script:', processResult.stdout);
      console.log('main.js finalizado com sucesso');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error in executePythonScript:', error);
  }
}
```

I've tried to implement assync functions to make the code waits for the python file to run, but without success.

Also, my idea is to pack the python scripts into an EXE later and redo the python script execution as an EXE, but, for a while, make this python script runs well will help.

I've tried to run the functions as async functions, and it didn't work.